# Firebase push notification not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I developed an android applicaiton. I used firebase for notification. I read firebase documentation then I made them respectively. I could send a push notification to one device by using InstanceID token. But I could not send push notification to all devices. Please help me.

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
                Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }

        Button subscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
        subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // [START subscribe_topics]
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
                Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to news topic");
                // [END subscribe_topics]
            }
        });

        Button logTokenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logTokenButton);
        logTokenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.muhammed.firebasepush">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest too

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: If you are using the example directly it won't work. For that example to work first you should register with FCM console. Create a project, provide the google-services.json file in the app/android folder.

Comment: *firebaser here* There was a problem with sending notifications through topic that was fixed this morning. See this [thread on the android-gcm group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!msg/android-gcm/pfOwV11FHrE/23ov5uXlBQAJ) for more information. If your problem still persists at the moment, it is unrelated to this outage.

Comment: There was a problem with firebase yesterday. Today It works for me. Thanks for everthing.

Comment: not able get token on `kitkat` devices

Answer (score 6):

You should include premission on manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**Update**

No premission are needed anymore, because "all the permissions required by FCM are now added automatically by library"

Comment: How do you change that? the manifest changes in every compilation, I dont know how to save those changes. Thanks.

Comment: @KRist I can't see anything in the docs that specifies that these permissions are required?

Comment: @KRist this is not needed anymore. See migration guide: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: @ADev yes thats true, I am updating that now, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all the solutions posted here and in other posts but they didn't work for me. I solved by manually uninstalling and reinstalling the app on my device. Hope this help.

Comment: Yes it saved me also as in debug mode whole apk doesn't changes, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! For me it was not working with Android M emulator.

Answer (score 2):

and dont forget,
I had the same problem and it is solved by defining enabled, exported to true in my service, trying to do like me,..

```
  <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "Send Now" in the firebase web console notifications gui try "Send Later" with a time shortly in the future.  Send Now may have a bug where it puts the date to send slightly in the past so it never gets sent.

Answer (score -1):

Go To https://console.firebase.google.com/ go to menu Notifications. here you can send messages directly to any particular device or all devices or based on topic your customer has subscribed.

Comment: i want to send message with the help of php i write a code unfortunately not going to device

Comment: This is not answering the question.