# Firebase Push notification not receving on some android devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented `firebase` fcm push notification for android app but it is receiving on some android devices only. Not receiving on Oppo, Vivo, Redmi and operating system Nougat and Oreo. I have implemented Messaging Service and Instance Service. Successfully  created token. Also implemented Boot receiver and give permission of Wake Lock and Receiver but still not receiving notifications.

Also tried these links:

[Xiaomi does not receive notification when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748107/xiaomi-does-not-receive-notification-when-application-is-not-running)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152649/what-is-protected-apps-in-huawei-phones

https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/issues/47

[Android - FirebaseApp / Firebase-Initialization is not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724761/android-firebaseapp-firebase-initialization-is-not-starting)

[Firebase push notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813748/firebase-push-notification-not-working)

Comment: your problem is device specific or OS specific ?

Comment: Both device specific and OS specific

Comment: @KhushbooAgarwal, yes, I too had same problem. it looks like the devices which has custom android OS, has this problem. It never generates Notification Token, which is used to send notification.

Comment: can we show your code